# Prove $1-\left|1-\frac{4\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x})}{\pi}\right|= \frac{2\sin^{-1}\left(2\sqrt{(1-x)x}\right)}{\pi}$ analytically

Tags: trigonometry

Prove $1-\left|1-\frac{4\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x})}{\pi}\right|= \frac{2\sin^{-1}\left(2\sqrt{(1-x)x}\right)}{\pi}$ analytically.

Thanks!

I had the idea that $\left|1-\frac{4\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x})}{\pi}\right|=\cos^2(x)$ and $\frac{2\sin^{-1}\left(2\sqrt{(1-x)x}\right)}{\pi}=\sin^2(x)$

so I could prove the equality using the pythagorean theorem.

So I looked at the different identities but I couldn't piece together a proper substitution.  I looked at the double angle formula . . .

Comment: The equality is not true take $x=1.$

Comment: Sorry, I edited the equation for the correct terms.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Let $x=t^2$. Then,

$\theta = \sin^{-1}(2t\sqrt{1-t^2}) \implies \sin\theta =2\sin\frac \theta2\cos\frac \theta2= 2t\sqrt{1-t^2}$

which leads to $\sin\frac{\theta}{2} = t \implies \frac{\theta}{2} = \sin^{-1}t$,

Comment: Proved the equality using your hints.  How did you know to do the things that you suggested in your hint?

Comment: @AndrewFerro - Glad to hear. I'm familiar with the inverse half-angle identity from experience.